# JQM- Swiping not working properly on Android devices

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Swiping is not working properly when we use Jquery Mobile on Android devices. Swiping is not smooth or sometimes it does not work at all.

```
$(document).off('swipeleft swiperight','.test')
            .on('swipeleft swiperight','.test', function(event) {       
    swipe(event);
});
```

.test - refers to a div class.

Please help. And, what is the problem in JQM, even it is not working on Samsung galaxy S4 native browser. Is there any easy way to achieve this without using any new plugins.

Comment: I tried to use swipe it works but is not accurate, my recommendation is to avoid swipe in hybrid apps like phonegap jquerymobile

Comment: To avoid swipe!!! it is a customer requirement. But, it is not an hybrid app.

Comment: Gajotres- Expecting an answer from you :)

Comment: Dont have enough reputation to start a bounty. Can some JQM experts help on this issue.

Comment: Why are no JQM experts answering this question. Looks like there are lot of bugs in JQuery Mobile which nobody wants to discuss or resolve.

Comment: @user694688 I have the same problem . Swipe events are not working properly in my MOTO G phone . SO I removed them and added click/tap event for buttons :(

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by a bug in JQM that has been resolved but is not yet implemented 
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/5534

Basically the min distance measured by the swipe event must take into account the pixel density of the device. So in JQM's case, the following change to touch.js will solve the issue:

```
horizontalDistanceThreshold = window.devicePixelRatio >= 2 ? 15 : 30;
verticalDistanceThreshold = window.devicePixelRatio >= 2 ? 15 : 30;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind event on that div directly..

```
 $('.test').swipeleft(function () {
    swipe(event); 
 }).swiperight(function () {
    swipe(event); 
 });
```

Or try to bind event with .live()

```
$(".test").live("swipeleft swiperight", function (event) {
   swipe(event); 
});
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: @user694688 - u said that sometimes swipe work and sometime it doesn't so, may be it's problem with binding event.

Comment: i mean to say it is difficult to swipe. Any idea on why JQM swipe event is not getting detected properly.

Comment: yes i have tried. The problem exists. Moreover, we cannot restrict users from using a specific browser. The expectation is that it should work seamlessly on browsers.